# Delete image from footer in LibreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

On some pages I have an image in the footer. I don't know how it got there and how to delete it. If I try to delete the footer my text goes all the way to the very bottom of the page. I want to have the same footer for every page. Please help me.

Here's a screenshot , the image (it has a capture) is in the footer and I can't move it , if I do,it replicated to all the pages:

[image: Screenshot]

I get this only on some of the pages. And if I go to Insert-> Footer I have here all kinds of footers. I have the option Insert-> Footer-> All but I don't think that's what I need.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? Can you click on the image to select it?

Comment: I tried to do Insert->Footer->Default Style , this deselects the footer. After this I repeat the steps and it gets me to the first page and I can edit the default footer , but it doesn't replicate to all the other footers, they stay as before

Comment: solved the different footer styles problem by setting Styles & Formating -> Page styles -> Default Style for every page that had a different style. Still can't find how to do this for the whole document at once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to click in the open space to the left (or right) of the image in order to place the focus on the page footer.  Now click on the image and press delete.  This shouldn't affect the text in the body of the page.  You should be able to edit both the text and the footer.

Comment: I tried this and the image is deleted, but how to set the same footer to all the pages?

Comment: If you type something in the footer (e.g. Same footer), doesn't it replicate in all the other pages?  This is what is supposed to happen.

Comment: It replicates to the pages that have the "SameFooter" , in my document I somehow have several pages with "SameFooter", some with "SameOtherFooter" and some others. I couldn't find how to reset the same footer to all of them

Comment: Go to Format - Page - Footer and check the box(es) labelled "Same content left/right" and "Same content on first page" to establish a consistent footer across all pages.